# Youtube Video 400 network Error when try to play video

Tags: android, regex, youtube-api

I am try to play video using `youtube video API`

When I put `static ID` means declare ID in file at that time code is working.

But when I try to fetch ID from `getIntent()` I also got ID but video not play.

I got There was problem with network.

Below is my code. Its working in this condition.

this is Video_Activity.java

```
public class Video_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

TextView textView1, textView2;
ScrollView scrollView;
WebView webView;
VideoView videoView;
private MediaController mController;
private Uri uriYouTube;
private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
Video video;
public String videourl;
// Google Console APIs developer key
// Replace this key with your's
String YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE;
String DEVELOPER_KEY;
//String Video_ids;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_);

    DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyC0rjDLc0jkYY0Z66QgOnkNmkOAyOqpqnI";

    // YouTube video id
    YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE = "yExScIwJftE";


    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#fdfafa'> Video View </font>"));

    final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment frag = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_view);
    if (frag == null) {
        frag = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.youtube_view, frag).commit();
    }

    frag.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (null != intent) {
        String Video_Title = intent.getStringExtra("Video_title");
        String Video_Desc = intent.getStringExtra("Vide_desc");
        //Video_ids = intent.getStringExtra("Video_ID");
        //Log.i("Video_Url", " " + YouTube_VideoPlayer);

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_video_Title);
        textView1.setText(Video_Title);

        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_video_desc);
        textView2.setText(Video_Desc);

        scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.Scroller_Id_video);
        scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, textView2.getBottom());
            }
        });
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure (YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason){

        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        }
        else
        {
            //String YouTube_VidePlayer = getIntent().getStringExtra("Video_Player");
            String YouTube_VideoPlayer = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, YouTube_VideoPlayer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess (YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,YouTubePlayer player,boolean wasRestored){

        if (!wasRestored) {
            // loadVideo() will auto play video
            // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically

            player.cueVideo(YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);

            //player.cueVideo(Video_ids);

            // Hiding player controls
            //player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Video_Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }
private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Now when i Used

```
public class Video_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

TextView textView1, textView2;
ScrollView scrollView;
WebView webView;
VideoView videoView;
private MediaController mController;
private Uri uriYouTube;
private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
Video video;
public String videourl;
// Google Console APIs developer key
// Replace this key with your's
public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyC0rjDLc0jkYY0Z66QgOnkNmkOAyOqpqnI";

// YouTube video id
//public static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE = "yExScIwJftE";
String Video_ids;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#fdfafa'> Video View </font>"));

    final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment frag = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_view);
    if (frag == null) {
        frag = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.youtube_view, frag).commit();
    }

    frag.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (null != intent) {
        String Video_Title = intent.getStringExtra("Video_title");
        String Video_Desc = intent.getStringExtra("Vide_desc");
        Video_ids = intent.getStringExtra("Video_ID");
        //Log.i("Video_Url", " " + YouTube_VideoPlayer);

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_video_Title);
        textView1.setText(Video_Title);

        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_video_desc);
        textView2.setText(Video_Desc);

        scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.Scroller_Id_video);
        scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, textView2.getBottom());
            }
        });
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure (YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason){

        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        }
        else
        {
            //String YouTube_VidePlayer = getIntent().getStringExtra("Video_Player");
            String YouTube_VideoPlayer = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, YouTube_VideoPlayer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess (YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,YouTubePlayer player,boolean wasRestored){

        if (!wasRestored) {
            // loadVideo() will auto play video
            // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically

            //player.cueVideo(YouTube_VideoPlayer);

            player.cueVideo(Video_ids);

            // Hiding player controls
            //player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Video_Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }
private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: It basically means your video_id extraction is not working.

Comment: i used to split videourl once see this :   
                String[] links = new String[]{video.getVideourl()};
                String[] video_ids = new String[links.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                    video_ids[i] = links[i].split("v=")[1];
                }

Comment: See my answer .. Please log the id's before you pass it.And see if it is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube id extraction is actually a different question but since this can solve your problem I am answering this. I usually do like this and it's working.

```
public void String getYoutubeId(String ytUrl)
{
String youtubeID ="";
if (ytUrl.contains("://youtu.be/")){
            youtubeID=ytUrl.substring(ytUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            ytUrl="http://youtube.com/watch?v=" + youtubeID;
        }else if (ytUrl.contains("watch?v=")){
            if (ytUrl.contains("&")){
                ytUrl=ytUrl.substring(0, ytUrl.indexOf('&'));
            }
            if (ytUrl.contains("https")){
                ytUrl.replace("https", "http");
            }
            youtubeID=ytUrl.substring(ytUrl.indexOf("watch?v=") + 8);
        }
return youtubeID;
}
```

Call `getYoutubeId(youtube url)` to get youtube id. Also print the id and compare it with the url you are passing and see if both matches.

Comment: intent = new Intent(context, Video_Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Video_title", Title);
                intent.putExtra("Vide_desc", Desc);
                intent.putExtra("Video_ID", Video_id.getYoutubeId(video.getVideourl()));

Comment: what error ? Null pointer ? Most probably your video object is null. Also what is "Video_id" in " Video_id.getYoutubeId(video.getVideourl()"  ?

Comment: video.getVideourl() means : i got several youtube links from json server, video is a object of Video class and Video_id is java class file ...i put above "getYoutubeId" code in Video_id.java class thats why am taking Video_id.getYoutubeId(video.getVideourl()